# Consuming SOAP Web service in sencha touch application

Tags: soap, sencha-touch, extjs, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I have to consume a SOAP web service using  sencha touch.

Can anybody help me

Can I use JSONP proxy to consume soap web service How ??

Please give some sample code or references.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach to accomplish your project is to develop some kind of middleware between your Sencha Touch app and your WS SOAP Service.

This middleware will handle WS petitions, transforming the results in JSON format and finally delivering to Sencha Touch app.

I've implemented this little architecture in one project some months ago and it worked like a charm. For the middleware, In my case, I worked with Java Apache Axis2 open source library

Hope you helps

Comment: can you provide me help regarding the use of middleware .

Answer (score -1):

i know it's too late...

I have a workaround for this problem. Maybe this is only suitable for development-Environment and not

productive-Environment. (Since it requieres Serverside configuration)

1. I configured our Server to allow CORS. therefore see: http://enable-cors.org/
2. start chrome with params: chrome.exe --disable-web-security
3. Make Ajax.request(...) Method:POST. Use the correct SOAP Envelope. helpfull:

http://www.soapclient.com/SoapMsg.html